# How to fix this formula - auto-populate " instead of '

Tags: google-sheets, concatenation, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to build an auto-populating string to search my database without getting an error message. I am stumped as to how to make `"` auto-populate as opposed to `'`.

I have pulled parts of strings from different places online to create this one (as this is way more complicated than what I have ever written) and as a result, I am struggling to edit the part I need.

```
="'" & join("' OR '",indirect("A2:A"&text(rows(A:A)-countblank(A:A),"0")), "'")
```

Actual: 'Football' OR 'football'
Intended: "Football" OR "football"

Answer (score 0):

try it like this:

```
=""""&TEXTJOIN(""" OR """, 1, A2:A)&""""
```

[image: 0]